# Libgdx, alpha Text Label using Shader not working when applied in Label create inside Action

Tags: java, libgdx, action, shader, scene2d

i've got trouble again when applied alpha text, it's next topic stackoverflow from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25688200/libgdx-alpha-text-using-shader-not-working)

Now first, i want to create some animation fade in Text per-character. i got idea about using TemporalAction to create it. the trouble is the alpha can't apply when label/text using shaders 'again'. (when i turn off the shaders, it's working)

here the Actions code, when im creating animation

```
    final Label lblR = new Label("READY!", new LabelStyle(Assets.assetFont.goldBoldBig, Color.BLACK));
    lblR.setPosition(Settings.width/2 - lblR.getWidth()/2, Settings.height/2 - lblR.getHeight()/2);
    DisplayTextAction action = Actions.action(DisplayTextAction.class);
    action.setDuration(0.3f);
    action.setText(lblR.getText());

    lblR.addAction(Actions.sequence(action, Actions.delay(0.4f), Actions.fadeOut(0.4f)));
```

now im include all of my files,

DisplayTextAction

```
public class DisplayTextAction extends TemporalAction{  
    public CharSequence completeText;
    private Label actor_clone;
    private int length_unreveal = 0;
    private int length_reveal = 0;

    @Override
    protected void begin() {
        actor_clone = new Label(completeText, new LabelStyle( ((Label)actor).getStyle().font, ((Label)actor).getStyle().fontColor ));
        actor_clone.setPosition(((Label)actor).getX(), ((Label)actor).getY());
    }

    protected void update(float percent) {
        if( (length_reveal == 0
                || (int)Math.round(completeText.length()*percent) + 1 != length_reveal )
                && (int)Math.round(completeText.length()*percent) + 1 < completeText.length()) {
            length_reveal = (int)Math.round(completeText.length()*percent) + 1;

            actor_clone.setText(completeText.subSequence(0, length_reveal));
            actor_clone.clearActions();
            actor_clone.addAction(Actions.alpha(0f));
            actor_clone.addAction(Actions.fadeIn(getDuration()/completeText.length()));
        }

        ((Label)actor).setText(
            completeText.subSequence(
                0,
                (int)Math.round(completeText.length()*percent)));
    }

    public void setText(CharSequence charSequence){
        this.completeText = charSequence.toString();
    }

}
```

Vert font

```
uniform mat4 u_projTrans;

attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord0;
attribute vec4 a_color;

uniform float u_newAlpha;

varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;
varying float v_newAlpha;

void main() {
    gl_Position = u_projTrans * a_position;
    v_texCoord = a_texCoord0;
    v_color = a_color;
    v_newAlpha = u_newAlpha;
}
```

frag

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

uniform sampler2D u_texture;

varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;
varying float v_newAlpha;

const float smoothing = 0.2;

void main() {
    float distance = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoord).a;
    float alpha = smoothstep(0.5 - smoothing, 0.5 + smoothing, distance);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoord).rgb, alpha*v_newAlpha);
}
```

Extend label from label scene2d

```
public class Label extends com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label {
    boolean shaderActive = false;
    ShaderProgram shader;
    public Label(CharSequence text, LabelStyle style) {
        super(text, style);
        if(style.font.getScaleX() > 1f) {
            shaderActive = true;            
            shader = Assets.assetFont.fontShader;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
        if(shaderActive) {
            batch.setShader(shader);
            shader.setUniformf("u_newAlpha", parentAlpha);
            super.draw(batch, parentAlpha); 
            batch.setShader(null);      
        }else {
            super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);             
        }       
    }
}
```

You can see in my action, i create new my extends label inside Actions, (i want to create CLONE but i can't, so i create manually). then im apply action on it. while 1st label animation play, the 2nd will create and play repeated each character of 1st label(+1 character).

I don't know why the alpha animation not working on it, (when it apply to shaders) i try using another actions it's working. I also try to turn off the shaders and it's working too. previously thread about using alpha in shaders font also working. but now it's not working.

(maybe that it's about creating actor inside action, so the alpha not working again ? i don't know.)

thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey, i got solve the trouble about alpha right now.
it's doesn't connect about creating Actor in Action. it's about the parent of actor.
The actor before has parent - group, therefore the alpha got working. but now if the actor act themself and add to stage it didn't work (coz parentAlpha is always 1). to apply it i must multiply with basecolor alpha of actor with parentAlpha.

```
shader.setUniformf("u_newAlpha", getColor().a * parentAlpha);
```